# output of my database do not appears in page when i use show function

Tags: php, laravel

output of my database do not appears in page when i use show function but when i use index function my data appears dont know why
i want to show data of specific id but all i have my text not data from database

my controller TestController

```
 class TestController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $tours = Tour::latest()->paginate(5);

        return view('test.index', compact('tours'))
            ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);

    }

    public function show(Tour $tour)
    {
        return view('test.show', compact('tour'));
    }
}
```

My Model Tour

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Tour extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'detail','price','duration','class','photo','startDate', 'endDate',
            'location',
    ];
}
```

my route

```
    Route::resource('mail','TestController');
```

my blade.php of show

```
        @extends('layouts.app')
    {{--@extends('layouts.navbar')--}}
 
    <div class="row tour-information">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <strong>Class</strong>
        </div>
    
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <span>name</span><span>{{$tour->name}}</span>
            <span>name</span><span>{{$tour->price}}</span>
        </div>
    
    </div>
    
    
    
    
    {{--<p>{{ $details['body'] }}</p>--}}
   
    <p>Thank you</p>
    @endsection
```

Comment: What Laravel version do you use?

Comment: im using laravel 7

Comment: What about if you dd($tour); in your show function?

Comment: App\Tour {#1235 ▼
  #fillable: array:9 [▶]
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
}

Comment: how can i get acces to fillable array which have my data

Comment: You data should be in #original which is currently empty. it's perhaps you don't have that modal in your database, please change the ID in the url and try again.

Comment: change ID to what ?

Comment: I meant, you may be trying to show a mail that is not in your database. Change the value of the ID in your URL. e.g yourdomain.com/mail/1  to yourdomain.com/mail/4

Comment: its working in another controller but this controller do not appears 
i did delete Id of 1 and 2 thats why im woking on id 4

Comment: It's definitely the mail that doesn't exist with that Id

Comment: i did try  now but the same result for id 1,2,3